# Fraktur (using yfonts): Specific quotation marks and semicolon

Tags: fonts, symbols, german

I'm currently using yfonts package for Fraktur hand and want to achieve a style as close to [this](http://bsb3.bsb.lrz.de/~db/1081/bsb10812028/images/index.html?id=10812028&fip=eayaewqsdasxsfsdrxdsydsdasyztseayaen&no=49&seite=310) as possible. While most characters seem sufficient to me I'm especially unhappy with quotations marks (and semicolon). Quotation marks are straight in the given link, but yfonts seems to use the modern german ones for Fraktur too. The semicolon is more rounded in the above link, quite angular in yfonts.

Example how it looks currently:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{yfonts}

\begin{document}
\frakfamily
„Text“;
\end{document}
```

Does someone know how to get those characters?

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  Can you add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a dirty way to get something more like your sample.  (It looks like the punctuation marks are not specifically fraktur, so you could get those from any normal font.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{yfonts}
\usepackage{rotating}

\def\`{,\kern-1pt,}
\def\'{\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{\`}}
\def\;{{\rm;}}
\def\.{{\rm.}}

\begin{document}
\frakfamily
\`Text\'\; und \`mehr Text\'\.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Edit by borartr:
I used your suggestion and meddled a bit with parameters. I now use the following which replaces your first \def command, because I personally think it looks best (which is of course subjective).

```
\def\`{\hspace{-1.3pt}\scalebox{0.9}{\rotatebox{12}{,}\kern-1.9pt\rotatebox{3}{,}}}
```

Feel free to use it if you're looking for something similar.

Comment: I really like your approach to the quotation marks, as this is probably exactly what they did to print those signs.

Comment: The problem with semicolon is the apostrophe sign imo, which does not seem to be drawable by hand due to its constantly thin shaft instead of a more natural one which would start bigger and thin down (as seen in the link).

Comment: @borartr, if I were to use this, I think I would make the quotation marks smaller and maybe decrease the space between them. the rotation looks very odd to me.

Comment: Decrease the space even more? It's already very small i think. You eed to care though if you use size 11 or some other settings this definition needs to be adjusted, I used it for fontsize 10. I tried to copy the style of these quotationmarks (https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f1/Schiller_-_Gedichte_296.gif). You may tell me if i succeeded. In time I may design other ones but I think they fit quite well.

Comment: @borartr, I meant relative to my definition and the picture.

Answer (score 3):

(too long for a comment, hence posted as an answer)

Here's a free translation of a paragraph from page four of the (German-language) user guide of the `yfonts` package:

> The quotation marks of the yfrak and ysmfrak font faces are no different from those of the Computer Modern Roman font face. This *not* a mistake, as it corresponds to the style of Breitkopf-Fraktur, which served as a template [for yfrak and ysmfrak]. Later [Fraktur] font faces used quotation marks that looked similar to the Fraktur comma. [emphasis in original]

Gottlob Immanuel Breitkopf -- the creator of "Breitkopf Fraktur" -- lived from 1719 to 1794. The link you've posted is to an 1844 reprint of Friedrich Schiller's collected works. It clearly uses a post-Breitkopf style for various punctuation marks -- and quotation marks in particular.

If you really need to reproduce the look of the 1844 publication, you probably shouldn't be using Breitkopf to begin with. I'm afraid I'm no expert in Fraktur font faces. Fortunately, Judith Schalansky's bilingual German/English book "Fraktur mon Amour" (Princeton Architectural Press, 2008) provides almost 130 pages of Fraktur font samples. Hopefully, one or more of them will meet your needs.

Comment: Your post is very interesting and explains the differences. I do not urgently need to reproduce this specific font, but like some of its style better. It's a matter of personal taste. Now that I've found good looking quotation marks I think I'll stick with Breitkopf style. Semicolons are not found that often so I can live with them eventhough I'd like the newer ones even better.